# How do i automatically fill out a shopify payment page using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, bots, shopify, puppeteer

`await page.type("#number", "1232132131")`

I tried to do that ^ but it's not working. Giving me an error saying that the selector is invalid.

I am trying to do this on the website culturekings.com.au. (on the payment page - where you put in your card details)

Comment: Excuse me for asking, but why would you check out automatically?

Comment: @Vaviloff It is for a personal use

Comment: That selector looks fine to me, you might try `[id=number]`

Comment: @pguardiario. I tried to do that but keeps saying element not found

Comment: Maybe it's in an iframe, or maybe it's not there.